# error in new package shiny jqui ( Error in callback :attempt to apply non-function )

Tags: r, shiny

hello I am trying to use this new package but I am keep on getting this error .
its a shiny jqui package . please someone help me I m new here 
I don't understand what this error mean

```
 library(shiny)
 library(shinyjqui)
 library(ggplot2)
 library(highcharter)
 server <- function(input, output) {}

  ui <- fluidPage(
    jqui_draggable(fileInput('file', 'File'))
    )

   shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Error]

Comment: What error? Please include the verbatim text of the error.

Comment: I have added the screenshot of error  r2evans

Comment: I see that your code is identical to the example on the [github page](https://github.com/yang-tang/shinyjqui), nice. My guess is it might have something to do with package versions (or R version). Can you include the output of either `devtools::session_info()` (if installed) or `sessionInfo()`? Please edit your question ... way too big for a comment :-)

Comment: yes I found the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into a similar error, see my issue on github:
https://github.com/Yang-Tang/shinyjqui/issues/23

It seems that:

```
jqui_draggable(fileInput('file', 'File'))
```

has to be changed to:

```
jqui_draggabled(fileInput('file', 'File'))
```

Full reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjqui)
library(ggplot2)
library(highcharter)
server <- function(input, output) {}

ui <- fluidPage(
  jqui_draggabled(fileInput('file', 'File'))
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I also made a pull-request to change the description, but for another function. But i guess the author is notified now.